# How can I use powershell to retrieve AD distinguishedName from the employeeID only?

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

What I'm trying to do is run a script which compares employee IDs from a CSV file to AD, and if they're NOT in the CSV but ARE in AD they should:
- be disabled
- have a termination date comment added to the description
- move to a different OU

The script I'm using below disables the account and adds the comment, but I get an error when it tries to move to different OU.  The error is:
Move-ADObject : Cannot find an object with identity: 'name1test' ...

I've tried a lot of things to adjust the script to get the samAccountName or distinguishedName using only the employeeID, but I've had no luck.  Any ideas?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory  

$TargetOU = "ou=Term,ou=Logins,dc=domain,dc=com"
$Date = Get-Date -Format MM-dd-yyyy
$Users = Import-Csv c:\ADTerm.csv | Select-object -ExpandProperty EmployeeID
$Terms = Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "ou=Test,ou=Logins,dc=domain,dc=com" -Properties EmployeeID | Where-Object{$_.EmployeeID -and ($Users -notcontains $_.EmployeeID)}

ForEach ($Term in $Terms)
{
    # Retrieve user sAMAccountName.
    $Name = $Term.sAMAccountName
    # Disable the user.
    Set-ADUser -Identity $Name -Enabled $False -Description "Terminated - $Date"
    # Move the user.
    Move-ADObject -Identity $Name -TargetPath $TargetOU
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distinguished name is one of the default properties that are automatically retrieved when you get an AD user, so all you need to do is replace this:

```
$Name = $Term.sAMAccountName
```

with this:

```
$Name = $Term.DistinguishedName
```